# owl carousel jump to specific slide and add class to it

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I used Owl Carousel to create a slide-based page with posts. I implemented data-hash to it, it works perfectly except that I need a function that adds a class to current hash item, so when changing hash location or receiving an external hash-link, this item to add a class.

Here is my code, I use Owl Carousel v2.3.4 and website is in wordpress:

```js
$('#post_top_slider').owlCarousel({
  loop: false,
  margin: 0,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  URLhashListener: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash',
  addClassActive: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 2
    },
    1000: {
      items: 3
    }
  }
});

$('#post_top_slider .owl-stage .owl-item').first().addClass('ps_actve');

$('#post_top_slider .owl-stage .owl-item').click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings('.owl-item').removeClass('ps_actve');
  $(this).addClass('ps_actve');
  var tab_id = $(this).children('.pts_item').attr('data-id');
  //alert(tab_id);
  $(tab_id).siblings('.ptsd_item').hide();
  $(tab_id).show();
});
```

The class that I need to add to hash item is "ps_actve". Website is [here](http://casacuteirezidential.ro/dev).

Comment: This is not about `owl`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone. I just put code below in owlcarousel.js, on line 3307:

```html
current.siblings('.owl-item').removeClass('ps_actve');
current.addClass('ps_actve');
var tab_id = current.children('.pts_item').attr('data-id');
//alert(tab_id);
$(tab_id).siblings('.ptsd_item').hide();
$(tab_id).show();
```

Comment: Modifying a library isn't recommended. It's easy for the changes to be lost if you update the package, and if you use NPM or the like your changes won't be propagated to other developers. Instead, use event hooks in your own code.

Comment: That is what I tried to do, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried to use hashchange.owl.carousel event but it doesn't work..